# MSVCP140D.dll is missing when distributing the executable

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have made [an encryption application](https://github.com/Cewein/Crypto.h/releases) in Visual Studio 2017.
 It works fine on my PC but, when I move the executable (.exe) on a different PC without Visual Studio, I get the error:

> MSVCP140D.dll missing

I don't want to download Visual Studio to fix this error, is there a way to avoid it?

Additional info:

- Compiled in VS2017
- made on Windows 10 x64
- use [Tiny file dialogue](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyfiledialogs/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should distribute release version of executable that will depend upon VS 2017 redistributable package rather than debug version that depends on debug runtime libraries (notice the `D` suffix in library name).

Answer (score -5):

You can link the runtime library statically, or provide the [VS 2017 redistributable](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

Comment: The *D.dll is the DEBUG version of the VC++ runtime, which is not included in the publicly available redistributable and, as far as I know (missing official reference here), you are not legally allowed to redistribute the DEBUG VC++ runtime to third parties.

Comment: @roalz: The trivial solution to that is to link with the release version. To link with the libraries you distribute. Thank you for pointing that out. It maybe needed saying.

Comment: FYI, I just commented, not downvoted, but I suppose you got them because of the "incorrectness" (let's say incompleteness) of your answer.